# Homology of the $n$-torus using the Künneth Formula

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to apply the Künneth Formula

$$H_{n}(X \times Y) \simeq \displaystyle \bigoplus_{r+s=n} H_{r}(X) \otimes H_{s}(Y)$$

to compute the homology groups of the $n$-torus. For the double torus, if I could write $\mathbb{2T}^{2} = \mathcal{U} \times \mathcal{V}$ it would be easier but I don't see how to do it.

Also, is there a way to relate $H_{\ast}(X \times Y \times Z)$ to $H_{\ast}(X)$, $H_{\ast}(Y)$ and $H_{\ast}(Z)$ and generalize the Künneth Formula?

I truly appreciate the help :]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write the two torus as $S^1 \times S^1$. Use that $H_0(S^1) = H_1 (S^1) = \mathbb Z$ and $H_i (S^1) = 0$ for $i > 1$.

Also use the fact that $\mathbb Z \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z$.

The answers you would get would be $H_0(T^2) = \mathbb Z$.

$H_1(T^2) = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$.

$H_2(T^2) = \mathbb Z$.

$H_i(T^2) = 0$ for $i >2$.

Now I must say that the Kunneth formula for homology has some $\text{Tor}$ terms. It works over here because homology groups of sphere are free.

That formula won't work for say $\mathbb RP^2 \times \mathbb RP^2$.

Anyway, that formula does work for coefficients in a field, since all modules over a field are free.

To relate product of three or more spaces, you can just apply the Kunneth formula repeatedly.

So for n torus, use the Kunneth formula repeatedly to obtain

$$H_k(S^1\times\dots\times S^1) = \bigoplus_{i_1 + \dots + i_r = k}H_{i_1}(S^1)\otimes\dots\otimes H_{i_r}(S^1).$$

Note that nonzero things appear only when the indices are $0$ or $1$. Use it to get the following :

$$H_k(T^n) = \mathbb Z ^{\binom{n}{k}}.$$

Comment: By $2\mathbb{T}^{2}$ I meant the double torus. I've used the Künneth Formula only to "verify" my answers since it's not difficult to compute the homology groups of the torus $\mathbb{T}^{2} = S^{1} \times S^{1}$. My goals was actually to compute the homology of the double torus. 

I didn't knew that the formual does not work for $\mathbb{R}P^{2} \times \mathbb{R}P^{2}$.

- Thanks for the help, really appreciate :]

Comment: @J. Lima: What is a 'double torus'? Do you mean a [genus two surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus-2_surface)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is. :)

Comment: @J. Lima: You should avoid the phrase 'double torus'. Say either a genus two surface or a connected sum of two tori. Anyway, the Künneth formula is of no use here as a genus two surface is not a product.

Answer (score 2):

For the two-dimensional torus, we have $T^2 = S^1\times S^1$. In general, we have

$$T^k = (S^1)^k = \underbrace{S^1\times\dots\times S^1}_{k\ \text{times}}.$$

The Künneth formula generalises in the way one might expect:

$$H_n(X_1\times\dots\times X_k) = \bigoplus_{r_1 + \dots + r_k = n}H_{r_1}(X_1)\otimes\dots\otimes H_{r_k}(X_k).$$